# Git Process: Could anyone please explain the check in/check out process?

Tags: git, git-extensions

I've used tortoise SVN for a few years but now moving into using Git. Could anyone please explain what the process is for doing the following in Git:

Get latest, 
Check in

I have managed to clone the repository successfully, made changes, committed then pushed the changes. Git says all is ok but I can't see the changes coming through on the remote server.

My set up is:

Remote server with Git repo on
and
Dev machine which connects to Git to take a local copy of the solution to work on.

also, when I view the history on my local machine, all is good! it shows all the history, when I go to the server, the changes are not showing!

If I am not doing it correctly, please let me know!

Thanks

Comment: This is probably better off on superuser than here.

Comment: Please post the commands you've performed, all **relevant** error messages *verbatim*, and the steps you've taken so far to research or resolve things on your own.

Comment: @Knyght: version control tools are on-topic for stackoverflow, as they are "software tools commonly used by programmers".

Comment: Oh! Fair enough. That's me told.

Comment: Were all of these changes on the same branch (likely master)?  Otherwise git defaults to only pushing the current branch rather than all branches.

Answer (score 1):

Use [git pull](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) to merge in changes from upstream into your local branch, and [git push](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) to push your local changes up to the remote repository.

The [Working with Remotes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) chapter of Pro Git has more examples.

Comment: I have done this and it says it has worked but if I look on the remote server, no changes!